# First time jQuery on xkcd

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a first time user of jQuery (and a huge fan already). I am trying to make the comic picture of [an xkcd page](https://xkcd.com/380/) `onclick` to [the explanation page](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/380).

Here's what I've done.

```
$("#comic").click(function(){
  return window.open("http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/" +       
    document.URL.split("/")[3]);
});
```

Is this efficient? Is this robust? Any jQuerying tips?

Comment: It won't work on the latest comic (http://xkcd.com/)

Comment: @Niet [Indeed it does.](http://goo.gl/oEBHsT)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides not needing to return the result of `window.open`, it looks pretty good. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1357118/1517919) for an explanation of what returning a value from event does. [From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/1517919),

> `return false` from *within a jQuery event handler* is effectively the
>   same as calling both  `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` on
>   the passed [jQuery.Event object.](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)
>
> `e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occuring,
>   `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up and
>   `return false` will do both. Note that this behaviour differs from
>   *normal* (non-jQuery) event handlers, in which, notably, `return false` [does *not* stop the event from bubbling up](http://jsfiddle.net/APQk6/).

Clearly, thats not what we want, so instead of returning the result of `window.open`, we should just omit the return.

---

This may not be necessary, but I would be more comfortable using

```
var comicID = location.pathname.split("/")[1];
```

over

```
var comicID = document.URL.split("/")[3]);
```

mainly because `http://` may be omitted from the URL and the code will still work (shouldn't ever be a problem either way). It's also more intuitive. I would also leave a comment for the code such as

```
// where path name looks like /156/ for xkcd.com/156/
```

Indentation would also help the code be more readable, however it's short so it doesn't matter too much... That said, I would write your code:

```
// when a user clicks the comic open the explanation
$("#comic").click(function(){
   // where pathname is the comicID eg /156/ for xkcd.com/156
   window.open("http://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/" + location.pathname.split("/")[1]);
});
```

Comment: you should explain what the link says about returning a value from an event just in case the link should die then this question will still be full of the knowledge that you have given the OP